# In LINQ how to check all fields of a inner list in a list with all fields of a inner list in another list?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

This is my model:

```
class A
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int? bId { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; }
}
class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<A> aList { get; set; }
    public B ()
    {
        aList = new List<A>();
    }
}
```

Now in my program I have two objects of b and want to compare both lists of a in the b type.

I have two lists of b:

```
bool checkingDuplicatedObjects(List<B> b1, List<B> b2)
{
    List<B> q = new List<B>();
    if (b1.Count != b2.Count)
        return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < b1.Count; i++)
    {
        var x = b1[i];
        var y = b2[i];
        q = (from n1 in x.aList
             from n2 in y.aList
             where n1.Value == n2.Value
             select x).ToList();
    }
    if (q.Count() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But I think this code is not completely logical.
Can you please help me?

Comment: When should `check` return true and what is with duplicates?

Comment: Also, isn't overwriting `q` in every iteration bad, don't really see how final `q` is of any significance to you.

Comment: Now you renamed the method from `check` to `CheckingDuplicatedObjects`, thanks. But does it make sense to return `false` if both lists have not the same count? That means both lists do not have duplicates if they have an unequal size, doesn't make any sense, does it?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic what do you mean? can you please explain what exactly your question is?

Comment: @TimSchmelter if the sizes are different so it means there are no posibility to have same objects

Comment: @Bahman: can you specify exactly what it means to have "same objects"?

Comment: You said that you have two objects of type `B` and that you want to compare inner lists `aList` of those two objects. What does it mean to compare? Do all of the elements have to be the same (have the same IDs and Values, or something else)? After that you say that you have two lists of objects `B`. What do you need to check then? Also, I'm not sure, but having `A` in `B` and `B` in `A` my cause you some problems later on (just saying...).

Comment: Does the order matter? If the two lists have the same objects but not in the same order?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic only aList because all Id fields are zero

Comment: I think it would be best if you gave an example.

Comment: @Magnus the order is not important

Comment: @Bahman: even with unequal sizes you can have two lists that contain all items of the other, considering duplicates. So still lacking specifications

Comment: @TimSchmelter Do you think using `valuesOfB1.All(valuesOfB2.Contains);` would do the trick? In combo with a length comparer ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there are many ways of doing this

```
    bool CheckDup(List<B> b1, List<B> b2)
    {

        if (b1.Count != b2.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b1.Count; i++)
        {
            B x = b1[i];
            B y = b2[i];

            var c = x.aList.Select(al => al.Value).ToList();
            var d = y.aList.Select(al => al.Value).ToList();

            bool isEqual = c.SequenceEqual(d);

            if (!isEqual)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

But we can make this look better by adding IEqualityComparer<> to A

```
class A: IEqualityComparer<A>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int? bId { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(A? a1, A? a2)
    {
        return a1?.Value == a2?.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(A a)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

With the Method now looking like this

```
    bool CheckDup(List<B> b1, List<B> b2)
    {

        if (b1.Count != b2.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b1.Count; i++)
        {
            B x = b1[i];
            B y = b2[i];

            bool isEqual = x.aList.SequenceEqual(y.aList);

            if (!isEqual)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Or we can go really wild and also add the interface to B

```
class B : IEqualityComparer<B>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<A> aList { get; set; }
    public B()
    {
        aList = new List<A>();
    }


    public bool Equals(B? b1, B? b2)
    {
        return b1.aList.SequenceEqual(b2.aList);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(B b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

With this further shortening the Method to this

```
bool CheckDup(List<B> b1, List<B> b2)
{

    if (b1.Count != b2.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }


    bool eq = b1.SequenceEqual(b2);

    return eq;
}
```

Now be mindful that SquenceEquals is also dependent on the order. So List [1 2 3] and [1 2 3] are the same but [1 2 3] and [2 1 3] are not. If you wanna ignore order then you would need to change some things.

The first example would need to be changed to

```
    bool CheckDup(List<B> b1, List<B> b2)
    {

        if (b1.Count != b2.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b1.Count; i++)
        {
            B x = b1[i];
            B y = b2[i];

            var c = x.aList.Select(al => al.Value).ToList();
            var d = y.aList.Select(al => al.Value).ToList();

            bool isEqual = c.All(d.Contains);

            if (!isEqual)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The Second to

```
    bool CheckDup(List<B> b1, List<B> b2)
    {

        if (b1.Count != b2.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b1.Count; i++)
        {
            B x = b1[i];
            B y = b2[i];

            bool isEqual = x.aList.All(y.aList.Contains) && x.aList.Count == y.aList.Count;

            if (!isEqual)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And in the third we would need to change Bs Equals Method to

```
public bool Equals(B? b1, B? b2)
{
    return b1.aList.All(b2.aList.Contains) && b1.aList.Count == b2.aList.Count;
}
```

Comment: @Bahman you are very much welcome. Be carefull though when you use the Interface, since it will change certain behaivior. For example if you wanna look if a List contains this EXACT object you could run itno problems.

Comment: Can I also use the below code?
bool isEqual = x.aList.All(y.aList.All) && x.aList.Count == y.aList.Count;

Comment: @Bahman no. First of all it will tell you its wrong when you try to type it and even if it would compile what would it even achive? All checks if all elements in a list meet the condition specified in its parameter. All(all) would if it could even compile try to look if every instance of x matches every instance of y which it wont

Comment: It always returns false because in one model , the Ids are bigger than zero of the objects in the list of A, while in another list Ids are all zero, I only want to compare string Value of A class.

Comment: @Bahman what Ids are you on about? The comparers I give you dont use the Ids. Only the values

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, my model had more fields

Comment: @Bahman ah ok is there still a problem?

Comment: No, thanks a lot for your advices

Comment: @Bahman no problem, have a nice day^^